# R sankey plot node limit?

Tags: r, igraph, rcharts, sankey-diagram

Is there a node limit to sankey plots? I am trying to create a plot with a lot of nodes and the following code fails to produce a plot (but gives me no error warning).

Any idea what is happening here?

```
# sankey chart using d3 plugin for rCharts and the igraph library

require(rCharts)
require(igraph)

# these are our vertices/nodes/end points/stages/categories/classes/whatever
nodes = c(1:36)

# the chart is basically a graph

pairs=c()
for (j in seq(1,36,by=4)) pairs=c(pairs,j,j+1,j+1,j+2,j+2,j+3)
pairs
g <- graph(pairs)
plot(g)
E(g)
E(g)$weights <- rep(c(16667,500,100),9)
length(E(g)$weights)

# convert to data frame with appropriate node names
edgelist <- get.data.frame(g)

# name columns as what is expected by plugin
colnames(edgelist) <- c("source", "target", "value")
edgelist

edgelist$source <- lapply(edgelist$source, FUN = function(x) {nodes[x]})
edgelist$target <- lapply(edgelist$target, FUN = function(x) {nodes[x]})
edgelist

# now we plot
sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()
sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey')
sankeyPlot$set(
data = edgelist,
nodeWidth = 15,
nodePadding = 15,
layout = 32,
width = 960,
height = 500
)
sankeyPlot
```

Comment: "View in browser" => "javascript console" => `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceLinks' of undefined`

Comment: The js library you set is empty, likely because http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey returns a 404.

Comment: 404 is not the problem.  There just isn't an index.html there.  I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

See http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/example_build_network_sankey.html.  As of now the source and target columns of the edgelist must be character.  Also, change the `lapply` to `sapply`.

I expect the resulting chart is still not what you want, but at least it shows up, so might want to look at the [link](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/example_build_network_sankey.html) mentioned above to make sure your network is as expected for a proper Sankey.

```
# sankey chart using d3 plugin for rCharts and the igraph library

require(rCharts)
require(igraph)

# these are our vertices/nodes/end points/stages/categories/classes/whatever
nodes = c(1:36)

# the chart is basically a graph

pairs=c()
for (j in seq(1,36,by=4)) pairs=c(pairs,j,j+1,j+1,j+2,j+2,j+3)
pairs
g <- graph(pairs)
plot(g)
E(g)
E(g)$weights <- rep(c(16667,500,100),9)
length(E(g)$weights)

# convert to data frame with appropriate node names
edgelist <- get.data.frame(g)

# name columns as what is expected by plugin
colnames(edgelist) <- c("source", "target", "value")
edgelist

edgelist$source <- sapply(edgelist$source, FUN = function(x) {as.character(nodes[x])})
edgelist$target <- sapply(edgelist$target, FUN = function(x) {as.character(nodes[x])})
edgelist

# now we plot
sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()
sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey')
sankeyPlot$set(
  data = edgelist,
  nodeWidth = 15,
  nodePadding = 15,
  layout = 32,
  width = 960,
  height = 800
)
sankeyPlot
```